Conversion of hour format in python flask
I want to change the hour format from 24 to 12. This is an attendance project and the following python code linked with HTML to show up the attendance from the database. And this is the code
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', selected_date='', no_data=False)

@app.route('/attendance', methods=['POST'])
def attendance():
    selected_date = request.form.get('selected_date')
    selected_date_obj = datetime.strptime(selected_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    formatted_date = selected_date_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    conn = sqlite3.connect('attendance.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT name, time FROM attendance WHERE date = ?", (formatted_date,))
    attendance_data = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()

    if not attendance_data:
        return render_template('index.html', selected_date=selected_date, no_data=True)
    
    return render_template('index.html', selected_date=selected_date, attendance_data=attendance_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

I have tried to do it by myself but I can't. I also tried with GPTs, but that was also a bug.

Do you want to change the format of selected_date and time fromattendance_data? do you want to do this in SQL, Python, or Javascript?

No formatted_date one. I want to do it in python or Javascript.

if time is a datetime object then you would use strftime() if a for loop or comprehension to cast it to the string format of your liking in the same manner as you have done with selected_date_obj

So what do I need to do?

try: attendance_data = [(p[0], p[1].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')) for p in attendance_data]

how do the data of time look like, mysql has many format function, which can do it
